# xml deserialization problem

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

i have a problem when i trying to use XmlSerializer to deserialize an xml file into a class i made myself, the xml file content is :

```
<UserInfoView xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iEverydayLog.Models.ViewModel" 
              xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <Address>Ultimo NSW</Address>

    <Id>685c7109-56c5-4a69-82d6-c9a286225d7e</Id>

    <Name>Tester Name</Name>

    <NumberOfCards>1</NumberOfCards>

</UserInfoView>
```

it failed with this message : There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

but when i remove these words:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iEverydayLog.Models.ViewModel"     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

it works ok, does any one know what happens here?

my class is defined like this:

```
    public class UserInfoView
    {
        public string Address;

        public string Name;

        public string Id;

        public int NumberOfCards;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the closing tag of UserInfoView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a default xml namespace; you can fix this by adding `[XmlRoot]` to tell it the namespace to expect:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iEverydayLog.Models.ViewModel")]
public class UserInfoView {...}
```

Comment: thanks very much.  problem fixed with this solution. cheers Marc